# Variables recognized as list instead of object

Tags: python-3.x, networking, types

I'm writing a program to building a CMST(mentor tree) through a set of given nodes. The method is to scan the area around a father node(backbone), and take every node inside it as leaves(terminals), while leftover nodes can find its father through specific part below

In this file, ListMentor refers to final mentor trees, while ListBackbone include a backbone and its terminals, techincally an element of ListMentor

ListPosition is the initial set of nodes used for the program, can be obtained through Topo_generate file.
The object Node is defined in the Node file
Other parameters are defined in the main file

The program run smoothly, until i tried to find the backbone of leftover nodes. When adding the part into the program, I started to receive
" 'list' object has no attribute '(object function)' ", while the named functions have been defined in the Object file, mostly in "for i in List___" loop

How should i fix this error ? Thank you for your answer

Mentor_test.py

```
import random 
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Node_test


num_inf = math.inf
num_ninf = -math.inf

Network_center = []
Backbone_1 = []

def MentorTree(ListPosition,C,centerIndex,NumNode,RadiusRatio,Limit):
    ListMentor = []
    
    print("Node is backbone if its W > W_th")
    
    W_th = 0
    for i in ListPosition:
        W_th = (W_th + i.w_get())/NumNode + 0.25
    print("W_threshold = ",W_th)
    for i in ListPosition:
        if i.w_get() / C > W_th:
            if i.get_name() == centerIndex:
                Network_center.append(i)
                ListPosition.remove(i)
            else:
                Backbone_1.append(i)
                ListPosition.remove(i)
    # for i in Backbone_1:
    #     print("Node:",i.get_name(),"is backbone")

    print("find access node for backbones")

    MaxCost = 0
    for i in ListPosition:
        for j in ListPosition:
            dc = i.get_distance()
            if dc > MaxCost:
                MaxCost = dc
    
    RM = RadiusRatio*MaxCost
    
    def AccessNode_update(_MentorTree,_ListPosition, _backbone):
        ListBackbone = []
        ListBackbone.append(_backbone)
        
        def is_exist(index,listbackbone,listmentor):
            for i in listbackbone:
                if i.get_name() == index:
                    # print("backbone: ",i.get_name(),"already exists")
                    return False
            for i in listmentor:
                for j in i:
                    if j.get_name() == index:
                        # print("access: ",j.get_name(),"already exists in backbone: ",i.get_name())
                        return False
            return True            
    
        for i in _ListPosition:
            if is_exist(i.get_name(),ListBackbone,_MentorTree) == True:
                if i.get_distance() <= RM:
                    # print("Node:",i.get_name(),"is access of backbone",_backbone.get_name())
                    ListBackbone.append(i)

        #backbone_limit
        def sort_by_distance_to_backbone(m):
            return m.get_distance()

        ListBackbone.sort(key = sort_by_distance_to_backbone)
        
        if Limit > 0:
            if len(ListBackbone)-1 > Limit:
                ListBackbone = ListBackbone[0:Limit+1]

        _MentorTree.append(ListBackbone)

        for i in ListBackbone:
            for j in _ListPosition:
                if i.get_name() == j.get_name():
                    _ListPosition.remove(j)

    #group tree part 1
    
    for i in Backbone_1:
        AccessNode_update(ListMentor,ListPosition,i)
    
    Node_test.printList2D(ListMentor)
    
   
>! find backbones for leftover nodes
>! 
>! print("for leftover nodes, find their backbones through their reward")
>! print("leftover nodes: ")
>! Node_test.printList(ListPosition)
>! 
>! center = Node_test.Node()
>! iloop = 1
>! while len(ListPosition)>0:
>! iloop = iloop + 1
>! #find center
>! sumx = 0
>! sumy = 0
>! sumw = 0
>! xtt = 0
>! ytt = 0
>! maxw = 1
>! maxdc = 1
>! maxaward = 0
>! 
>! for i in ListPosition: (error position)
>! sumx = sumx + (i.pos_get_x()) * i.get_traffic()
>! sumy = sumy + (i.pos_get_y()) * i.get_traffic()
>! sumw = sumw + i.get_traffic()
>! if i.get_traffic() > maxw:
>! maxw = i.get_traffic()
>! xtt = sumx / sumw
>! ytt = sumy / sumw
>! 
>! center.pos_set(xtt, ytt)
>! 
>! for i in ListPosition:
>! i.set_distance_to(center)
>! if i.get_distance() > maxdc:
>! maxdc = i.get_distance()
>! 
>! for i in ListPosition:
>! i.set_award((0.5 * (maxdc - i.get_distance() / maxdc)) + (0.5 * i.get_traffic() / maxw))
>! if i.get_award() > maxaward:
>! maxaward = i.get_award()
>! 
>! for i in ListPosition:
>! if i.get_award() >= maxaward:
>! e = Node_test.Node()
>! e.copyNode(i)
>! ListPosition.remove(i)
>! AccessNode_update(ListPosition, ListMentor, e)
>! break
>! 
>! print("final mentor trees: ")
>! 
>! Node_test.printList2D(ListMentor)
>! 
>! 
>! return ListMentor
```

The elements of every Lists here is a Node object, so i was expect every time calling elements, system will return the object to work. But it seems when i add the process to find backbones through rewards for leftover nodes, Python recognized my individual variables as List ?

This is my source code

Node_test.py

```
# Thư viện
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

num_inf = math.inf
num_ninf = -math.inf


# Các cài đặt mặc định


# Lớp mô hình hóa các nút
# Thuộc Tính:
#   Tọa độ x,y
#   Khoảng cách tới nút trung tâm đang tạm xét (tính theo Đề các)
#   Tên nút đánh từ 1 đến nút MAX
class Node:
    name = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0

    # MENTOR
    traffic = 0
    weight = 0
    awardPoint = 0
    distance = 0

    # Esau William
    weight_ew = 0
    weight_of_group = 0
    group_node_to_center = 0
    thoa_hiep = num_ninf
    cost_to_center = num_inf
    next_connect = 0
    group_size = 1


    def __init__(self):
        self.ListConnect = []

    def create_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.group_node_to_center = name
    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    ##connection
    def set_connect(self,i):
        #print("Go set neighbor:",i,"in Node:",self.get_name())
        self.ListConnect.append(i)

    def check_connect(self,i):
        if i in self.ListConnect:
            return True
        return False

    def remove_connect(self,i):
        self.ListConnect.remove(i)

    def get_list_connect(self):
        return self.ListConnect

    def reset_list_connect(self):
        self.ListConnect.clear()
        
    def set_next_connect(self, index):
        self.next_connect = index
        
    def get_next_connect(self):
        return self.next_connect
    
    ## position

    def pos_create(self, MAX):
        self.x = random.randint(0, MAX)
        self.y = random.randint(0, MAX)

    def pos_set(self, x, y):
        self.x = round(x,2)
        self.y = round(y,2)

    def pos_get_x(self):
        return self.x

    def pos_get_y(self):
        return self.y

    ##distance

    def set_distance_to(self, other):
        self.distance = round(math.sqrt((self.pos_get_x() - other.pos_get_x()) ** 2 + (
                self.pos_get_y() - other.pos_get_y()) ** 2),4)

    def get_distance(self):
        return self.distance

    def compare_position(self, other):  # Return 1 if same 0 if not same
        return (self.pos_get_x() == other.pos_get_x()) and (self.pos_get_y() == other.pos_get_y())

    ##traffic
    def set_traffic(self, t):
        self.traffic = t
        
    def get_traffic(self):
        return self.traffic
    
    def traffic_create(self):
        self.traffic = random.randint(1,10)
        return self.traffic
    ##weight
    def w_set(self, w):
        self.weight = w
        
    def w_get(self):
        return self.weight

    ##E_W
    def set_ew_pre(self, name, x, y, w):
        self.name = name
        self.group_node_to_center = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.weight = w
        
    def set_weight_ew(self, w):
        self.weight_ew = w
        self.weight_of_group = w

    def get_weight_ew(self):
        return self.weight_ew

    ##group

    def set_weight_of_group(self, w):
        self.weight_of_group = w

    def set_group_node_to_center(self,index):
        self.group_node_to_center = index

    def get_group_node_to_center(self):
        return self.group_node_to_center

    def set_group_size(self,s):
        self.group_size = s

    def get_group_size(self):
        return self.group_size

    def get_weight_of_group(self):
        return self.weight_of_group

   ##award
   
    def set_award(self, t):
        self.awardPoint = t
    
    def get_award(self):
        return self.awardPoint
    
    ##thoahiep
    def set_thoahiep(self, t):
        self.thoa_hiep = t
    
    def get_thoahiep(self):
        return self.thoa_hiep

    ##other 
    def set_cost_to_center(self, c):
        self.cost_to_center = c

    def get_cost_to_center(self):
        return self.cost_to_center

    def copyNode(self, other):
        self.x = other.pos_get_x()
        self.y = other.pos_get_y()
        self.name = other.get_name()
        self.traffic = other.get_traffic()

    def printInitial(self):
        print('Node: {:<3} | Position: x = {:<4} y = {:<4} | Traffic: {:<2} | Weight Esau William: {:<2}'.format(self.get_name(),
                                                                                                       self.pos_get_x(),
                                                                                                       self.pos_get_y(),
                                                                                                       self.get_traffic(),
                                                                                                       self.get_weight_ew()))

    def printMentor(self):
        print('Node: {:<3} | Position: x = {:<4} y = {:<4} | Traffic: {:<2}'.format(
            self.get_name(),
            self.pos_get_x(),
            self.pos_get_y(),
            self.get_traffic()))

    def printCenterPress(self):
        print('Node trung tâm trọng lực: Position: x = {:<6} y = {:<6}'.format(round(self.x,2),round(self.y,2)))

    def printEW(self):
        print(
            'Node: {:<3} | Position: x = {:<4} y = {:<4} | Thỏa hiệp: {:<9} | Liên kết mới khi thỏa hiệp tới node: {:<3} | Trọng số nhánh: {:<2} | Node về tâm {:<3} | Khoảng cách về tâm {:<4}'.format(
                self.get_name(),
                self.pos_get_x(),
                self.pos_get_y(),
                round(self.get_thoahiep(), 4),
                self.get_next_connect(),
                self.get_weight_of_group(),
                self.get_group_node_to_center(),
                self.get_cost_to_center()))
        print("List Connect:", self.ListConnect)

    def print(self):
        print(self.get_name(),end=' ')


'''




'''


# Tạo một số hàm

# Hàm sắp xếp danh sách dựa trên tọa độ x của node


def sortListPosition(m):
    return m.pos_get_x()


def printList(_list):
    for i in _list:
        i.print()
    print()

def printInitialList(_list):
    for i in _list:
        i.printInitial()

def printMentorList(_list):
    for i in _list:
        i.printMentor()

def printEWList(_list):
    for i in range(1,len(_list)):
        _list[i].printEW()


def printList2D(_list):
    for i in _list:
        for j in i:
            print(j.get_name(),"->", end=' ')
        print()


def find_index_node(m,ListPosition):
    for i in range(0, len(ListPosition)):
        if ListPosition[i].get_name() == m:
            return i
    return 0

def matplotList(_list, MAX):
    xpos = []
    ypos = []
    npos = []
    for i in _list:
        xpos.append(i.pos_get_x())
        ypos.append(i.pos_get_y())
        npos.append(i.get_name())

    for i in range(0, len(_list)):
        plt.text(xpos[i], ypos[i], str(_list[i].get_name()), color='black', size=7.5, rotation=0.,
                 ha="center", va="center",
                 bbox=dict(facecolor=(1., 0.8, 0.8), edgecolor='none', boxstyle='round')
                 )
    plt_margin = MAX * 0.05
    plt.axis([-plt_margin, MAX + plt_margin, -plt_margin, MAX + plt_margin])
    plt.show()


def matplotconnectpoints(x, y, n1, n2,ListPosition):
    p1 = n1
    p2 = n2
    x1, x2 = x[p1], x[p2]
    y1, y2 = y[p1], y[p2]
    plt.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], 'k-')


def matplotListToCenter(_list, MAX):
    xpos = []
    ypos = []
    npos = []
    for i in _list:
        xpos.append(i.pos_get_x())
        ypos.append(i.pos_get_y())
        npos.append(i.get_name())

    #for i in range(1, len(_list)):
    #    matplotconnectpoints(xpos, ypos, i, 0)

    plt.plot(xpos, ypos, 'ro', markersize=5, markerfacecolor='w',
             markeredgewidth=1.5, markeredgecolor=(0, 0, 0, 1))

    plt.plot(xpos[0], ypos[0], 'ro', markersize=7.5, markerfacecolor='r',
             markeredgewidth=1.5, markeredgecolor=(0, 0, 0, 1))

    plt_margin = MAX * 0.05
    plt.axis([-plt_margin, MAX + plt_margin, -plt_margin, MAX + plt_margin])


def matplot_esau_william(_list, MAX):
    xpos = []
    ypos = []
    npos = []
    for i in _list:
        xpos.append(i.pos_get_x())
        ypos.append(i.pos_get_y())
        npos.append(i.get_name())

    plt.text(xpos[0], ypos[0], str(_list[0].get_name()), color='white', size=7.5, rotation=0.,
             ha="center", va="center",
             bbox=dict(facecolor=(1., 0., 0.), edgecolor='black', boxstyle='round')
             )
    for i in range(1,len(_list)):
        plt.text(xpos[i], ypos[i], str(_list[i].get_name()), color='black', size=7.5, rotation=0.,
                 ha="center", va="center",
                 bbox=dict(facecolor=(1., 0.8, 0.8), edgecolor='none', boxstyle='round')
                 )

    for i in range(1, len(_list)):

        for j in _list[i].get_list_connect():
            matplotconnectpoints(xpos, ypos, i, find_index_node(j, _list), _list)


    plt.plot(xpos, ypos, 'ro', markersize=5, markerfacecolor='w',
             markeredgewidth=1.5, markeredgecolor=(0, 0, 0, 1))

    plt.plot(xpos[0], ypos[0], 'ro', markersize=7.5, markerfacecolor='r',
             markeredgewidth=1.5, markeredgecolor=(0, 0, 0, 1))


def matplot_mentor(_list_mentor,MAX):
    for _list in _list_mentor:
        xpos = []
        ypos = []
        npos = []
        for i in _list:
            xpos.append(i.pos_get_x())
            ypos.append(i.pos_get_y())
            npos.append(i.get_name())

        plt.text(xpos[0], ypos[0], str(_list[0].get_name()), color='white', size=7.5, rotation=0.,
                 ha="center", va="center",
                 bbox=dict(facecolor=(1., 0., 0.), edgecolor='black', boxstyle='round')
                 )
        for i in range(1, len(_list)):
            plt.text(xpos[i], ypos[i], str(_list[i].get_name()), color='black', size=7.5, rotation=0.,
                     ha="center", va="center",
                     bbox=dict(facecolor=(1., 0.8, 0.8), edgecolor='none', boxstyle='round')
                     )

        plt.plot(xpos, ypos, 'ro', markersize=5, markerfacecolor='w',
                 markeredgewidth=1.5, markeredgecolor=(0, 0, 0, 1))

        plt.plot(xpos[0], ypos[0], 'ro', markersize=7.5, markerfacecolor='r',
                 markeredgewidth=1.5, markeredgecolor=(0, 0, 0, 1))
    plt_margin = MAX * 0.05
    plt.axis([-plt_margin, MAX + plt_margin, -plt_margin, MAX + plt_margin])



def matplot_total(_list,MAX):
    for i in _list:
        matplot_esau_william(i, MAX)
    plt_margin = MAX * 0.05
    plt.axis([-plt_margin, MAX + plt_margin, -plt_margin, MAX + plt_margin])
```

Topo_generate.py

```
import random
import math
import Node_test
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def sortListPosition(m):
    return m.pos_get_x()

def Topo_generate(Max,NumNode,centerIndex): 
    
    ListPosition = []
    
    for i in range(NumNode):
        n = Node_test.Node()
        if i == centerIndex: 
            norm = int(Max/2)
            n.pos_set(norm,norm)
            n.create_name(centerIndex)
            n.w_set(999)
            ListPosition.append(n)
        else:
            n.pos_create(Max)
            n.create_name(i)
            ListPosition.append(n)
        
    EdgeMatrix = [[0] * NumNode for i in range(NumNode)]
    
    def set_edge(m,n,value):
        EdgeMatrix[m][n] = value
        EdgeMatrix[n][m] = value
    
    TrafficMatrix = [[0] * NumNode for i in range(NumNode)]
    
    def set_traffic_route(m,n,value):
        TrafficMatrix[m][n] = value
        TrafficMatrix[n][m] = value
        
    for i in ListPosition:
        for j in ListPosition: 
            if i == j: 
                set_traffic_route(i.get_name(),j.get_name(),0)
                continue
            else:
                set_traffic_route(i.get_name(),j.get_name(),i.traffic_create())
            # print("traffic from node ",i.get_name()," to node ",j.get_name(),": ",TrafficMatrix[i.get_name()][j.get_name()])
    # print(TrafficMatrix)
    
    for i in range(len(ListPosition)):
        if ListPosition[i].get_name() == centerIndex:
            pass
        else:
            ListPosition[i].w_set(sum(TrafficMatrix[ListPosition[i].get_name()]))
    
    for i in ListPosition:
        for j in ListPosition: 
            i.set_distance_to(j)
            set_edge(i.get_name(),j.get_name(),i.get_distance())
            if i == j:
                continue
            # else:
            #     print("distance from node ",i.get_name()," to node ",j.get_name(),": ",EdgeMatrix[i.get_name()][j.get_name()])    
    
    for i in ListPosition:
        if i.get_name() == centerIndex:
            print("Node",i.get_name(),"has coord: x =",i.pos_get_x(),"y =",i.pos_get_y()," weighted:",i.w_get(),", as network Center")
        else:
            print("Node",i.get_name(),"has coord: x =",i.pos_get_x(),"y =",i.pos_get_y()," weighted:",i.w_get())

    return ListPosition
```

Main_test.py

```
import Node_test
import Topo_generate_test
import Mentor_test

Max = 1200
NumNode = 100
centerIndex = 10
# W_th = 0.589
C = 100
RadiusRatio = 0.5
backbone_lim = 5

ListPosition = []
ListPosition = Topo_generate_test.Topo_generate(Max,NumNode,centerIndex)
    
# Node_test.matplotList(ListPosition,Max)
Backbone_node = Mentor_test.MentorTree(ListPosition,C,centerIndex,NumNode,RadiusRatio,backbone_lim)
'''
```